# Password_verify doesn't check correctly

Tags: php, passwords

Big problem with password_verify.

In my db there is a column:

```
password:  $2y$10$1k72g4qYgd4t5koC5hj8sOit3545GfO5EhaIwVRfIiA2/eC3Hnu5e ('b')
```

When I want to check in order that this password is equal the letter a it given my completely 2 different codes.My code:

```
$hash = password_hash('b', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pass = getPassword($email);
echo $hash . ", " $pass;
```

and it gives me:

```
$2y$10$oJbeQqGSee.pLcBNxqRzUecoCGc9fin7IF.evDVanN1pjmtIINSD2,
$2y$10$1k72g4qYgd4t5koC5hj8sOit3545GfO5EhaIwVRfIiA2/eC3Hnu5e
```

Why there are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `password_hash()` before inserting into your storage and then when you verify you should use `password_verify()`

```
$pass = getPassword($email);
$verify = password_verify('b', $pass);

if ($verify) {
     // passwords match
}
else {
    // passwords do not match
}
```

See: [password-verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for more info

Answer (score 2):

It's because when not specified by the user, `password_hash` will generate a random **salt**. Salt is a string that is appended to a password before hashing. Thanks to salts being random, two users with same password will still have different hashes in database.

Good summary of the topic can be found [on the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)#Example_usage)

In order to verify that the password is correct, you shouldn't manually compare hashes, which may be different with each use of `password_hash` because of random salts, but rather use function `password_verify`